# Eigenvectors of anti-circulant matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2514187/eigenvalues-of-anti-circulant-matrix) and [this other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62466/eigenvalues-of-anti-circulant-matrices-using-1-circulant-matrices) regarding the eigenvalues of a real anti-circulant matrix.  Those posts contain some comments about the eigenvectors.  However I cannot realize which are the eigenvectors of such a matrix.  Could you advise me on that?  I am mainly interested in the eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue equal to the sum of the first row of the anti-circulant matrix (which is the same sum of any row or column).  However, it would be nice to know all the eigenvectors.

EDIT:  If I am not wrong, the eigenvector associated to the sum is $v=(1, 1, 1, \ldots, 1)^t$.  What about the other eigenvectors?

EDIT:  The matrix is real.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have an anti-circulant matrix $A = (a_{ik})_{n\times n}$, the first row of $A$ is $r_1 = [a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n]$ and the $i$-th row is $r_i = [a_i, a_{i+1}, \cdots, a_n, a_1, \cdots, a_{i - 1}]$.
**For this answer, I will first give a construction of eigenvectors and eigenvalues, then prove that all eigenvalues and eigenvectors can be obtained in this way.**

For the **first part**, let's consider the [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix) $D = [d_1, d_2, \cdots, d_n]\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, where
$$ d_l = [1, \omega^{l - 1}, \omega^{2(l - 1)}, \cdots, \omega^{(l - 1)(n - 1)}]^T, l = 1, \cdots, n $$
with $\omega = e^{-2\pi j/n}$ and $j = \sqrt{-1}$.
For simplicity of notation, we consider $a_{n + i} = a_i$.
Then we can verify that
$$ r_id_l = \sum_{k = 1}^{n}{a_{k + i - 1}\omega^{(l - 1)(k - 1)}} = \omega^{-(l - 1)(i - 1)}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{a_{k}\omega^{(l - 1)(k - 1)}} = (r_1d_l) \cdot d_{li}^* $$
Denote $b_l = r_1d_l$ and we have $Ad_l = b_ld_l^{*}$, where $d_l^{*} = [d_{l1}^{*}, \cdots, d_{ln}^{*}]^{T}$ (not the same as the conjugate transpose $d_l^{H}$).
Similarly, consider $d_l^{*}$ and it is easy to verify that $Ad_l^* = c_ld_l$ where $c_l$ is defined as $c_l = r_1d_l^* = \sum_{k = 1}^{n}{a_{k}\omega^{-(l - 1)(k - 1)}}$.

Now consider $u_l$, $v_l$ such that $u_l^2 = c_l$, $v_l^2 = b_l$ (specified later) and we find
$$ A(u_ld_l + v_ld_l^{*}) = u_lb_ld_l^{*} + v_lc_ld_l = u_lv_l\cdot(u_ld_l + v_ld_l^{*}) $$
Define $\overline{d}_l = u_ld_l + v_ld_l^{*}$ and it is clear that $\overline{d}_l$ is an eigenvector of $A$ and $\lambda_l = u_lv_l$ is the corresponding eigenvalue.
Notice that $d_l$ is one column vector of $D$, and different column vectors of $D$ give eigenvectors of $A$ from the above procedure.
Specially, the all-ones vector $[1, 1, \cdots, 1]^T$ is the first column of $D$, i.e. $d_1$, and $d_1^* = d_1$ so $\overline{d}_1$ is just a multiple of $d_1$, which gives the eigenvector you mentioned in the question.

Now for the **second part**, let's try prove that all eigenvectors can be obtained from the above procedure.
To begin, it is worth discussion that the definitions of $u_l$ and $v_l$ are  actually not unique.
Given that the matrix $A$ is real, then we know that $b_l = c_l^*$.
Without loss of generality, consider $b_l = \rho_l e^{-2j\theta}$ and $c_l = \rho_l e^{2j\theta}$ with $\rho_l\ge 0$, then correspondingly we have $u_l = \pm\sqrt{\rho_l}e^{j\theta}$ and $v_l = \pm\sqrt{\rho_l}e^{-j\theta}$.
To this end, we can see that for every vector $d_l$ we have two possible pairs of eigenvalues and eigenvectors:
$$ \lambda_l^{(1)} = \rho_l, \quad\overline{d}_l^{(1)} = \sqrt{\rho_l}\left(e^{j\theta}d_l + e^{-j\theta}d_l^{*}\right) = 2\sqrt{\rho_l}\cdot\text{Re}(e^{j\theta}d_l) $$
$$ \lambda_l^{(2)} = -\rho_l, \quad\overline{d}_l^{(2)} = \sqrt{\rho_l}\left(e^{j\theta}d_l - e^{-j\theta}d_l^{*}\right) = 2\sqrt{\rho_l}\cdot j\text{Im}(e^{j\theta}d_l) $$
which means there are $2n$ eigenvectors in total.
However, as we soon will see, there are redundancy in these vectors.

First for $d_1$, which is all-ones vector, $b_l = c_l\in\mathbb{R}$, so $\theta = 0$ or $\pi$, $e^{j\theta}d_1\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\overline{d}_1^{(2)} = 0$ which cannot be an eigenvector.
This reasoning is the same for $d_{n/2 + 1}$ (when $n$ is even) which is also a real vector taking values from $\{\pm 1\}$.

For $l\ge 2$, we can verify that $d_l = d_{n + 2 - l}^{*}$, so $\{\overline{d}_l^{(1)}, \overline{d}_l^{(2)}\} = \{\overline{d}_{n+2-l}^{(1)}, \overline{d}_{n+2-l}^{(2)}\}$.
So there are pairs of $d_l$'s that give the same set of two eigenvectors.
On the other hand, if $l\le n/2$,
$$ \rho_l = |b_l| = \left|\sum_{k = 1}^{n}a_k\omega^{(l-1)(k-1)}\right| $$
are different for different $l$'s, so $\{\pm\rho_2, \cdots, \pm\rho_{\lceil n/2\rceil}\}$ are $2(\lceil n/2\rceil - 1)$ distinct eigenvalues of $A$.

Combining the above two paragraphs, we can calculate the number of distinct eigenvalues by: if $n$ is odd, then there are $2(\lceil n/2\rceil - 1) + 1 = n$ distinct eigenvalues; if $n$ is even, then there are $2(n/2 - 1) + 2 = n$ distinct eigenvalues.
So in conclusion, all eigenvalues and eigenvectors can be found from the procedure in the first part, and this completes are proof.

Comment: Sorry, I do not fully understand your notation.  Is $j$ the imaginary unit (instead of being $i$)?  Is $x^*$ the conjugate (and not the conjugate traspose)?  Is $\bar{x}$ just a name (and not the conjugate)?  Thanks.

Comment: @ASdeL Sorry for the ambiguity. I have updated my answer according to your edition, and given a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Hi.  I think that $b_l = \rho_l e^{-2j\theta}$ and $c_l = \rho_l e^{2j\theta}$.  If not, then $u_l = \pm\sqrt{\rho_l}e^{-j\theta}$ and $v_l = \pm\sqrt{\rho_l}e^{j\theta}$. (signs are swapped).  Besides, should't it be $\theta_l$ instead of $\theta$?  Finally, I think that $\sqrt{\rho_l}\left(e^{j\theta}d_l - e^{-j\theta}d_l^{*}\right) = -2\sqrt{\rho_l}\cdot j\text{Im}(e^{j\theta}d_l) $ (although the sign does not change the direction of the eigenvector, current equality is false).

Comment: I think it should be $e^{j\theta}d_1\in\mathbb{R}^n$ instead of $e^{j\theta}d_1\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @ASdeL For $z = a+jb$ the imagine part $\text{Im}(z) = b$, not $jb$. So I think my equation is right. Also I don't see what changes are made if we swap the sign of $\theta$. Surely it should be $\theta_l$, I just omit it as $\theta$ is not quite important. As for the $e^{j\theta}d_l\in\mathbb{R}^n$, that's true and I will modify my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi.  IMO signs are swapped because according to your definitions and equations $\rho_l e^{2j\theta}=b_l=v_l^2=\left(\pm\sqrt{\rho_l}e^{-j\theta}\right)^2=\rho_l e^{-2j\theta}$.  That is, $b_l = \rho_l e^{2j\theta}$ is not compatible with $v_l = \pm\sqrt{\rho_l}e^{-j\theta}$ because $b_l=v_l^2$.  In other words, you must change sign of $\theta$ in $b_l$ (and $c_l$), xor in $v_l$ (and $u_l$).

Comment: @ASdeL Oh ok thanks that's right.